# How to regex test a string for a pattern while excluding certain characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I'm getting nowhere with this...

I need to test a string if it contains `%2` and at the same time does not contain `/`. I can't get it to work using regex. Here is what I have:

```
var re = new RegExp(/.([^\/]|(%2))*/g);
var s = "somePotentially%2encodedStringwhichMayContain/slashes";

console.log(re.test(s))  // true
```

**Question**:
How can I write a regex that checks a string if it contains `%2` while not containing any `/` slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the link referred to by Sebastian S. is correct, there's an easier way to do this as you only need to check if a single character is not in the string.

```
/^[^\/]*%2[^\/]*$/
```

[image]

EDIT: Too late... Oh well :P

Comment: went with this one. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
^(?!.*/).*%2
```

Comment: and sorry. I switched to the solution of Cu3PO42.

Answer (score 1):

either use inverse matching as shown here: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

or use indexOf(char) in an if statement. indexOf returns the position of a string or char in a string. If not found, it will return -1:

var s = "test/";
if(s.indexOf("/")!=-1){

//contains "/"

}else {

//doesn't contain "/"
}

Comment: thanks. I also was looking at indexOf but I was looking if it could be done with regex, too. Checking the link